# Amazing Jutsu (Technique)

Tags: c#

Hy..I'm newbie here.. Please does anyone knows, how to create such a character(sprites) to have a different Style Technique and different kind of movement, so he/she can alternate many technique to defeat his/her opponent...

I wanna make my 2d character his/her power had a technique like rasengan, I mean
for the first the jutsu its just spining around above his/her hand and then going bigger and much bigger so can create a massive giant ball/light/swords or etc blow up when he/she use that technique to defeat his/her opponent?
the e.g of game like Disgaea, Final Fantasy, Suikoden, and another RPG, MMORPG game

How the coding is to combine the sprite with his/her different style of technique, and what should I do? Please your guide, thank's a lot... ^_^

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is very confused and confusing. It mentions concepts (like "jutsu" and "rasengan") without explaining what those are. Could you clarify more about what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my trouble word..
So I wanna acomplish my spritesheet and make him/her use the technique who can blow up like 'rasengan'.. I mean if i using the 2d animation like 'spritesheet' how's the ways to acomplish this..

Answer (score 2):

The character and the attack needs to be animated separate. That way you can swap out different attacks as needed.Usually the special attack is a particle effect generated using code, or a separate sprite. You probably could attach the attack to the character using an offset, for e.g. taking the character to be the attack's point of origin and positioning it (x,y) coordinates away.

If it's just a runic effect kind of thing that flares up around the character, you might be able to just use a 2D translucent overlay on top of the character.

You would definitely need to have more character animations though, if your attacks are radically different enough. For example, one set for your Rasengan thrusting, one set for Fireball blasting, and so on. You might probably be able to generalise your attacks as a series of basic classes (ThrustAtk class, MouthBlastAtk) and further inherit from them (LightningThrustAtk, WindThrustAtk, FireMouthBlastAtk, etc.)

Comment: Alright, but I still don't get it along...

So, I've to animated many particle and combine into a single strike..

Comment: For your Rasengan example - Are you familiar with explosion spritesheets? (Go Google it) Something like that. The fireball gets larger with each frame. So you can have your Rasengan grow larger until the last few frames, then just loop the last few frames to have the sphere twirl around. And if you wanted Chidori, have a separate, lightning spritesheet and have it loop and zigzag. So diff attacks use diff spritesheets.